# What is the word for the response to a ping

Tags: single-word-requests

Someone may say, "I'll ping him and see if I can get a response." If I want to ask if the ping was successful, how can I refer to the response? Is there a more clever way than "Did your ping get a response?" I feel like *pong* may be clever, but not very clear.

Comment: As someone in the tech industry, I can safely say *pong* is the most widely accepted term for a ping response. ACK is generally considered outdated and originated as a response to ENQ, not *ping*.

Comment: @Eric As someone in the "tech" industry over the last 25 years, a person who suggested "pong" without talking about paddle controllers would be seen as a person who didn't know their history.  The old-school response was "<x> is alive", or at least an ACK (acknowlegement).  Ping pong it a table-tennis game, not a computer term.

Comment: Answers are a bit relative since this is technical slang.  In my experience, when spoken to verbally, the response tends to be "ACK" as in "I received an ACK from the guy."  If someone enters a "Ping" in chat or email, the response does tend to be "Pong". Again, this is IT slang for "(Are you/)(Is someone) there?" and since it carries a (very) slight humorous connotation, the response is tended to be equally as slightly-funny.

Comment: @RLH Yes, and ACK would imply an affirmative response; NAK would be the opposite (negative acknowledgement).

Comment: I disagree with the other "tech" people.. a proper ping is usually ICMP, which doesn't get an ACK because it is not connection oriented like TCP.  The term for a response to a ping packet is a "RESPONSE".  That being said, in the IM context, where ping is really a misnomer, and annoys some tech purists, I would use response or answer as the term, never pong.

Comment: As someone in the tech industry who was writing software before he could legally drive a car, I can safely say I hear both _pong_ and _ack_ in regular usage (even within one office.)

Comment: @EdwinBuck: didn't know their history? [RFC 1459](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1459.txt), 4.6.2 "Ping Message" and 4.6.3 "Pong Message": `PONG message is a reply to ping message.` May 1993 - that's 21 years ago. There are many places that use PING, not only ICMP...

Comment: See also AYT/ACK "Are you there/Acknowledge", from serial comms, Ping/Echo from sonar, Ping/echo request/Echo Reply from IP/ICMP, but since you are talking about a person, Response, Reply or Answer would be best.

Comment: @drs For some reason, a lot of answerers are providing tech jargon, yet your scenario says nothing about computer networking (or submarines).  I take your question to be about two coworkers in any random office setting, not necessarily where there are any computers (or submarines), discussing someone who has been out of contact about something.  Can you clarify what you're looking for?

Comment: It's so amusing that this question is at english.stackexchange.com, not at superuser or just stackoverflow.

Answer (score 41):

In the lost days of IRC, the response to *ping* was ***pong***.

Comment: And before IRC, it was the first commercially successful computer game.  Depending on the crowd, you'll get either recognition or confusion.

Comment: @Edwin, and before the computer game, it was a physical game (still is), and before the physical game it was used in sonar (attested since the early 1940s), and *ping* as onomatopoeia for the sound of an object striking sharply has been around since the 1830s, and a verb since the 1850s ("ping that can" would mean "shoot that can"). Point being that all these meanings trace back to onomatopoeia, and are intuitively comprehensible, especially with the support of context (I promise you no one had to ask how Parker Brothers came up with the name "ping pong", even without sonar experience).

Comment: @DanBron the game of table tennis and its nickname of ping pong predates radar (as we know it, not the theory) by roughly 60 years.

Comment: @DanBron I enjoy a good game of ping-pong too, but the computer term ping has it's roots in sonar concepts.  Which lends me to consider what the terminology would be like if it were otherwise, for example, would we "serve up" a "ping"?  And if that were so, wouldn't the response be a "return"?

Answer (score 25):

The [Jargon File](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/P/ping.html) seems to suggest that "ack" (or "nak", in a sense of "I'm here but don't have time for this") might be understood in sufficiently nerdy circles.

```
ACK/NAK Acknowledged/Not Acknowledged
```

[The Story of Ping](http://ftp.arl.mil/mike/ping.html)

Comment: I would definitely agree with ACK as a programmer, and that was the first thing that popped in to my mind when I saw the question. The only problem I see is that if you are using ping to mean contact in general I am not sure that ACK is as applicable since most people will likely not know what an ACK is.

For those wondering, an ACK is the response TCP sends to ACKnowledge receipt of a packet.

Comment: @3-Laws-Safe, indeed.  It also has use in systems programming.  I have a friend with which I keep the `SYN?` (reply `SYN;ACK!`) and `SYN;SYN;ENQ?` (reply `ACK!` or `NAK!`) alive.  I've even used `0x06`.  I don't think it's necessarily bad to stress language.  If it's not understood, a question about it makes for more interesting conversation.

Comment: "If I want to ask if the ping was successful, how can I refer to the response?" Are you suggesting that "Did you get ACK?" (or "an ACK") is the way to ask about a reply?

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Yes, I would probably say "I didn't get an ACK yet."

Comment: Common ping (echo) is ICMP which does not use acknowledgements (ACK).  You have an echo request and an echo response or no response.

Comment: -1 This is an example of trying to be *too* clever.  `ACK` is the response in TCP, while `ping` uses ICMP. Using `ACK` here is a misnomer.  Of course, any developer who half-understands networking will get what you're trying to say, and it certainly makes you *look* nerdy if that's the goal; but to someone who actually understands the topic, this makes you look foolish.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: The term "ping" is used to describe "Are you there" queries in many protocols besides ICMP, and "ACK" is used to describe acknowledgments in many protocols besides TCP/IP.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft So you don't like the author? Good for you. The answer is still insightful.

Answer (score 22):

The response to a ping, in computer networking terminology, is an ICMP [Echo reply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Technical_details)

Perhaps then "Did you get a reply" would be most correct.

Edit: Original RFC (defining document for internet protocols, courtesy of @digitaltrauma): [RFC 792](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc792#page-14)

Comment: The question isn't about ICMP, it's about ordinary people pinging each other. Only the geekiest computer nerd would make use of the underlying network terminology in this metaphor. Also, don't forget that network ping is just a metaphor derived from SONAR pings.

Answer (score 14):

The output of the Windows/MSDOS ping command seems to leave very little room for interpretation:

```
C:\>ping google.com

Pinging google.com [205.213.114.59] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 205.213.114.59: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=127
Reply from 205.213.114.59: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=127
Reply from 205.213.114.59: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=127
Reply from 205.213.114.59: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=127

Ping statistics for 205.213.114.59:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 0ms
```

According to over a billion computers, the response to a ping is called a "Reply."

Of course, the term "ping" predates computers.  Submarine sonars emit a "ping" and wait for an "echo," at least according to this source:
http://maritime.org/doc/fleetsub/sonar/chap6.htm

Comment: By the same logic that was a single ping, though clearly it was actually 4.

Comment: Of course, Linux ping output is `<n> bytes from <host>: <stuff>`... I don't think Windows really counts. Also, I think it just *faking* networking.

Comment: +1 The other answers are cute, but "reply" is the term I would *actually use* in conversational speech.  (Disclaimer: I was born in the 80s)

Comment: @MadTux, what do you mean "just _faking_ networking"? Both Windows and Linux are actually sending data packets with the `ping` command.

Comment: @BrianS I'm sorry. I just don't have a very high regard of Microsoft Windows.

Comment: @MadTux: That shines through in your ludicrous notion that it somehow cannot perform networking.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Really? :P

Comment: "According to over a billion computers" Yeah because if Windows was wrong about this, nobody would buy a Windows computer and the "majority vote" would have turned out completely different (=sarcasm).

Answer (score 11):

It's slang based on different technologies, and the slang response depends on which technology you are more familiar with:

1. Sonar: *echo* or *pong* (itself a joking slang in the context).
2. Table tennis (real or simulated): *pong*
3. Internet: *echo* (from ICMP ECHO packets), *ACK* (from ACK in TCP/IP) or *pong* (from the above being slangily used for ICMP Echo responses).
4. IRC: *pong* (IRC has a PING command that works over IRC analogous to ICMP PING but checking for IRC client connection and network distance over that network, rather than the underlying TCP/IP connection, the response to it is PONG).
5. Weblogs: *pingback* (from a type of link-back mechanism used by some blogging software).

Comment: there is no `ICMP ECHO` there are `ICMP ECHO reply` and `ICMP ECHO request`.

Comment: In passive sonar, the response is also called a *return.*

Comment: @OllieJones I've never heard, or heard of, that being used as a reply to *ping* in the slang sense of contacting a person, though.

Answer (score 10):

There is no word for this. Be clear; just say *Did your ping get a response?* or *Did you get a response for your ping*?

*Reply* is an alternative to *response*, here.

And of course if you are in a technical context, where you really mean use of the network command `ping`, then you might want to ask **what** response was received, as the content of the `ping` response is often important.

Comment: In a technical (networking) context, "reply" is best. The formal names in the RFC for the messages used are "ICMP Echo Request" and "ICMP Echo Reply". It's not true that the content is important. As the standard (RFC 792) states: "To form an echo reply message, the source and destination addresses are simply reversed, the type code changed to 0, and the checksum recomputed."

Comment: @stevenKath: 1. There are 4 occurrences of *response* and 5 of *reply* [here (Linux `man` page)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ping).  And 10 of *response* and 5 of *reply* [here (Microsoft ping page)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737478(v=ws.10).aspx).  2. If it were true that the content were unimportant then there would be no reason for the content to be specific (anything beyond, say, ACK), or for it to follow the particular command options/switches you provide.  3. But the technical details of `ping` are not really important in the current context.

Comment: This is the best answer. `ACK` and `pong` can work in certain circles, but "response" or "reply" leaves no room for ambiguity or confusion outside of tech circles (and the term ping has come to be used outside of network ICMP protocols anyway).

Answer (score 2):

Sending a 'ping' is quite common in I.T to see if something is responding at the other end, such as a server or website. I might call the response a 'pingback'. I am not quite sure if it fits for your purpose as it's usually associated with automatic notifications for linking of blog messages.

Comment: pingback would be appropriate if the response to your ping is automatic. e.g. An out-of-office e-mail notification.

Comment: You might call it a pingback, but no-one else does...   https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pingback

Comment: @GreenAsJade Apparently, _Alo_ is not the only one. I don't know (I don't care?), what books.google.com has to say about this, but in my country (Poland) and in my area (IT industry) using "pingback" as an answer to "ping" is so obviously common, that I was actually quite surprised, that the only answer with "pingback" here has so low score...

Comment: @trejder Of course, ngram is only one reference/source, nothing definitive.  But - one source is better than none ;)   I wonder if Alo is also from Europe?   Would that make 'pingback' a 'European-English' phrase?   I work in IT in Australia and I've never heard it... to my ears it sounds "made up and foreign", not a word that sounds "right".

Comment: @GreenAsJade Yes I am in the UK and for me the word pingback feels self-explanatory and in this situation you could ask it to someone a week later and it doesn't need any further explanation or reference, which is what the OP was asking.. e.g. 'Did you get a pingback from James in the end?'. Maybe a European thing, I am not sure. I do like 'Ack' though but it does rely on the other person knowing what that means.

Comment: Interesing!  I would 'hear' that sentence as "Did you get a ping back from James in the end".   IE a ping is something you get back from a ping.   Ah well ... language is wierd :)

Comment: I work in computers in NY, USA and when I saw pingback, I assumed it was a European term.

Answer (score 0):

I always thought that a successful ping resulting in you receiving a ping! This is based on my understanding of sonar (where the verb 'to ping' originated) where if you are able to hear a "ping" off something then you hit it (i.e. it is there).

So "I sent a ping" and if I was successful then "I received a ping".